# Automatically generated form and get values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I generated automatically with PHP form, for example:

```
<form id="stack">
    <input type="text" name="aaa" pos="one"> <br />
    <input type="text" name="bbb" pos="one"> <br />
    <input type="text" name="aa3456" pos="two"> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" pos="one" value="Water"> Water
    <input type="radio" name="group2" pos="one" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gvv" pos="two" value="Water2"> Water
    <input type="radio" name="gvv" pos="two" value="Beer2"> Beer<br>
    <INPUT NAME="options" pos="one" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="o1">
      Option 1<BR>
    <INPUT NAME="options" pos="one" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="o2">
      Option 2<BR>
    <INPUT NAME="options"  pos="one" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="o3">
      Option 3<BR>
    <INPUT NAME="options2" pos="one" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="11">
      111<BR>
    <INPUT NAME="options2" pos="one" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="22">
      222<BR>
    <INPUT NAME="options2"  pos="one" TYPE="CHECKBOX" VALUE="33">
      333<BR>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

i dont know how is inputs and how the are named. I know only - they are attribute pos="one". In form can be also pos="two" etc.

If they are attribute pos="one" they must be not null.

How can i check this? In my example should be:

input text with name **aaa** & **bbb** should be not null

one input radio with name **group2** must be checked - with value Water or value Beer.

minimum one input checkbox with name **options** shoud be checked.

minimum one input checkbox with name **options2** shoud be checked.

How can i get all inputs where pos="one" with jQuery? Maybe function each and filter? But how?

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/T8nNs/4/

EDIT: If some input is null/not checked i would like receive alert('error').

Comment: i dont know how to get all inputs with pos="one"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would grab the `pos` attribute, the input name, and the input val like this:

```
var pos = $('input').attr('pos');
var inputName = $('input').attr('name');
var inputVal = $('input').val();
```

From there, you can start doing your validations:

```
var pos = '';
var inputName = '';
var inputVal = '';
$('#stack').submit(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    pos = $this.attr('pos');
    inputName = $this.attr('name');
    inputVal = $this.val();
    if (pos === 'one') {
      if (val === null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        // positive answer
      }
    } // etc.
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but what it is val === null? before havent var val. and how can i in positive answer get all values and name for all these inputs?

Comment: I apologize, I changed the name of the variable. It should be `inputVal`. In order to get those values, you would actually rewrite the variables within the `each()` statement. Let me revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for example :

```
$('input[pos="one"],input[name="gvv"]').change(function() {
    alert('changed');
})​
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/T8nNs/9/

To perform validation on the form you could use [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: but how to check this if i click on submit?

Comment: See my answer - use the `submit` event

Comment: but i dont know names these inputs

Comment: Use `$('input[pos="one"]')` this will give you all elements where `pos=one` ... thats what you need ?